# Docker Compose: Django, uWSGI, NGINX without Proxy (different containers)

Tags: docker, nginx, uwsgi

My **docker-compose.yaml** is

```
version: '3'

services:

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    depends_on:
      - web
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    network_mode: "host"  # Connection between containers

  web:
    build: .
    image: app-image
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/app-name
    command: uwsgi /app-path/web/app.ini
```

**NGINX conf file is**

```
upstream web {
    server 0.0.0.0:80;
}

server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name web;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias "/app-static/";
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass      http://web;
    }
}
```

---

So basically I have Django and uWSGI in one container 'web' and NGINX in container 'nginx'. I linked both using NGINX via Proxy and both worked fine. (I somehow needed 'network_mode: "host"' without that didn't work)

Since they are different containers, I cannot use .sock file (Unless I use some volume hacks to share the .sock file which is not good!)

Even though this works, I have been asked to avoid using NGINX via proxy, so is there any other way to connect these two?

Searching didn't get me alternatives. I tried